# How Principal components can be determined using Statistical Inference? : doubt in the book "Using Multivariate Statistics"

Tags: pca, inference, multivariate-normal-distribution

In chapter 13 (Factor analysis and PCA) of the book ["Using Multivariate statistics"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0205849571), under the section 13.3.2.2, how big an issue is the non-normality of the data is discussed. From what is given, I understand that multivariate normality is not a concern when PCA is used descriptively. But the authors also say,

> multivariate normality is assumed when statistical inference is used
>   to determine the number of factors.

I'm not able to figure out what do they exactly mean here. How can statistical inference be used to determine the no. of factors/components? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are indeed some, mostly chi-square based tests. But doesn't the book consider them to some extent? I thought it ought to.

Comment: In my knowledge, this issue is not given in detail in the book. Can you provide me some links where I can know more about this ?